# Circular Array... weird

Tags: modifiers

So I tried to use the array with an empty and rotate. I tried every possible formula. My shape would just go crooked and not keep its angle. I ended up doing a duplicate/rotate with 3D cursor as my rotation base. Any tips on how to make this work fast/easy would be greatly appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Nice model BTW. It's possible the local axis of the arrayed element is not aligned with the axis of rotation, as defined by the empty? If you're working aligned to World space, try Ctrl-A applying the scale and rotation of the arrayed element.

Comment: hello, maybe share just the object you wanted to array + the empty so that we can test

Comment: ok thank you @RobinBetts. Will try.

Comment: @moonboots will post later on. Thank you for the help.